# Highchart EMA, Price & MACD plot

Tags: highcharts

I'm looking to produce a chart like [this](https://codepen.io/raj2619/pen/vYZeVOv) with [data here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aiw4HhkSppTin2wKiVMXUFiFku-1?e=RVbN8v)

I'm trying to play with this chart on [codepen](https://codepen.io/raj2619/pen/vYZeVOv)

The attached data file has the following values -

```
1) Date
2) Open, High, Low, AdjustedClose - Plot Candlestick
3) Volume - Plot Volume
4) EMA1 & EMA2 - Plot moving averages on candlestick chart
5) macd_1, macds_1 & macdh_1 - Plot first set of MACD
6) macd_2, macds_2 & macdh_2 - Plot second set of MACD
7) macd_3, macds_3 & macdh_3 - Plot third set of MACD
```

The moving averages & MACD need not be calculated via javascript. It's already in the JSON data.

Need an export menu on the chart & smoothed plot of the EMA

There are 3 sets of MACD with macd, macds & macdh (histtogram) values all of which need to be on their own panels & have different positive & negative zone colours

The chart title needs to be of some colour centred at the top of chart. when we move mouseover the chart, the OHLC values & date need to be displayed

There is another field in the data called "Entry_type". When the value is "B" (Buy) a green balloon needs to be displayed below the candle & when it is "S" (Sell), a red colour needs to be display above the candle

All the plots need to be on movable panels (movable  so to speak in HTML terms). The idea here is if needed then I would need to be able to keep say 2 MACD panels one below the other on left-hand side & move the third one to the right-hand side so that the actual price chart has good amount of vertical space on the page to show data clearly.

Need to set "groupData" to true, which means MACD, EMA & Volume will also need to adjust to that.

I am new to javascript charting which is making my life really hard to get all of this working. Could I please request some help to implement these features?

Comment: Hi @usert4jju7, All you need to do is to prepare the correct data format for each series and create a separate y-axis for each pane. I have prepared a simple example with your data here: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-d-zn9oj?file=/demo.jsx but I don't know how exactly you want to map your data.

Comment: Thank you @ppotaczek. I've now managed to build the chart I am after except for one piece of feature which is artefact. I'm struggling to work out how to put a lbel ont he chart . I've created a separate question for it  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69234383/highcharts-should-is-use-data-labels-or-annotation-or-something-else-and-how Please could you help me with this piece?

Comment: Please post your above comment into the answer section & i'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to prepare the correct data format for each series and create a separate y-axis for each pane. I have prepared a simple example with your data here:

```
for (i; i < dataLength; i += 1) {
  date = new Date(data[i].Date).getTime();
  ohlc.push([
    date, // the date
    data[i].Open, // open
    data[i].High, // high
    data[i].Low, // low
    data[i].Close // close
  ]);

  volume.push([
    date, // the date
    data[i].Volume // the volume
  ]);

  if (data[i].ema_1) {
    ema1.push([date, data[i].ema_1]);
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-d-zn9oj?file=/demo.jsx