# Highcharts - Should Is use data labels or annotation or something else and how?

Tags: highcharts

I have built a stock chart using Highcharts. A few blocks from a massive dataset containing years worth of data looks like below -

```
 {
    Date: "2018-02-16",
    Open: 0.6406,
    Close: 0.6697,
    High: 0.6697,
    Low: 0.6406,
    Adjusted_close: 0.5538,
    Volume: 284808,
    Entry_type: "B"
  },
  {
    Date: "2020-01-15",
    Open: 1.02,
    Close: 1.02,
    High: 1.04,
    Low: 1.02,
    Adjusted_close: 0.9508,
    Volume: 209591,
    Entry_type: "S"
  }
```

What I'm trying to do is display a circle or balloon or square or whatever shape containing either `B` or `S` based on the value of `Entry_type`.

I've spent quite sometime trying to understand the examples from Highcharts website. Unfortunately I am not able to make a connection from the examples to my particular use case.

Please could someone help me out here?

Comment: I think you are doing a candlestick chart right ? Where do you want to show these value ? Next to all values or only on hover ?

Comment: Thanks for coming back Core972. Yes candlestick chart. I want to display B or  as applicable permanently on the chart. ‘B’ should be below the candlestick and ‘S’ above the candlestick please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using the `render function` [API Link](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render)

```
    chart: {
        events: {
            render: function() {
                try {
                    this.series[0].data.forEach(point => {
                        if (point.Entry_type === "B") {
                            point.dataLabel.attr({y: point.plotLow});
                        } else if (point.Entry_type === "S") {
                            point.dataLabel.attr({y: point.plotHigh - 20});
                        }
                    });
                } catch (error) {
                    // continue
                }
            }
        }
    },
...
    series: [{
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            backgroundColor: "#fdfc59",
            shape: "circle",
            formatter: function () {
                return this.point.Entry_type;
            }
...
```

[Edited Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/j5atwcfL/1/)

**Edit 3 full example**

[Full Codepen](https://codepen.io/taxman972/pen/NWgYvQz)

Comment: Thanks a yon. I’ll try this on the massive dataset shortly. I see that you’ve added x: 160691940000 to every  data block. Should I add this to the dataset by running a for loop  before passing the data to chart ? Also, please could you add a balloon or circle with a light background colour and print B/S inside it?

Comment: @usert4jju7 , I changed the shape the shape and the background color.

Comment: Thank you @Core972. I applied this to my project & it isn't working unfortunately. Please can you verify this codepen - https://codepen.io/thandle11/pen/gORemWL

Comment: I put  the project into debug mode on Chrome & I see that console.log(point.Entry_type) is producing "undefined". I can't see the property "Entry_point" in the "point" object

Comment: I tried using flags as shown here - https://www.highcharts.com/demo/stock/flags-shapes. No luck. Just can't work out what is wrong...

Comment: @usert4jju7 you can't put canddleStick AND flagShape data in the same data serie. If you want to use flagShape too you must create a second data serie. For now here a working [Codepen](https://codepen.io/taxman972/pen/NWgYvQz)

Comment: Fantastic. This works. Thanks a gazillion

Comment: Hello @Core972 - Would you be bale to help me with another one please - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69295190/show-date-alongside-ohlc-values-in-candlestick-chart