# Show Date alongside OHLC values in candlestick chart

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to show Date along with `OHLC` values on candlestick chart.

Currently the chart [here](https://codepen.io/thandle11/pen/zYzLexL) shows date only at the bottom of the chart on the date axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you just need to disable *split* property that is responsible for splitting the tooltip to multiple labels.

API reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.split

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e0ytgxsn/

```
tooltip: {
  split: false
}
```